# RDF Schema for org-mode

Tags: rdf, org-mode, semantic-web, rdfs

I would like to create an RDF schema world for org-mode. As you may know, an org-mode document is based on an hierarchical outline where headings are the main grouping entities.

```
* March auxiliary
:PROPERTIES:
:HLEVEL: 1
:END:

** :TOGRO: json/rdf grokking
:PROPERTIES:
:HLEVEL: 2
:END:

*** :GROKKING: json grokking intro 
:PROPERTIES:
:HLEVEL: 3
:END:

*** :GROKKING: test of simple worg snippet
:PROPERTIES:
:HLEVEL: 3
:END:
```

Probably the best view/breakdown of this is an org-element parse of an org-mode file. (See [here](http://ergoemacs.org/emacs/elisp_parse_org_mode.html). Brace yourself for ads.) In my schema, each "HLEVEL" would have a URI noun. I've not heard of an RDF schema for org-mode, so I guess I need to know if there is any sort of URI "upstream" from a URI I might create, e.g., `http://example.org/org-mode-hlevel-1` is a sub-node/special type of of an existing, established URI for, in general, document hierarchy nodes. Is there an existing schema for documents that are in a hierarchical outline format that I can start with, work down from? Then I'd probably need a whole URI noun vocabulary for the TODO wilderness. Then one for the Babel world, especially the metaprogramming. What I envision is an org-element sort of parser that would generate OWL, N-triples.

Actually, Roam Research already has the rudiments of what I'm eventually aiming at. See [this](https://youtu.be/HzZFm-fb-LI) video. This is what I'm aiming at.

Comment: I'd use blank nodes for headings etc, not URIs... As for the 'heading' class, see https://lov.linkeddata.es/dataset/lov/terms?q=heading&type=class

Answer (score 0):

I just learned about :CUSTOM_ID" in org-mode, which looks like a good way to assign identity to org mode text. So, for example, in somefile.txt,

```
* TODO my heading
   :PROPERTIES:
   :CUSTOM_ID: id432
   :myProp:   vanilla
   :END:
```

could end up as

```
@prefix ex: <http://www.somedomain.com/ns/ex> . 

<somefile.txt#id432> dc:title "my heading" ; 
                     ex:status "TODO" ;
                     ex:myProp "vanilla" .
```